# Getting invaders to shoot

Tags: c#, xna

I have added a class dedicated to the missile. Code is shown below:

```
 class Missile
    {
        Vector2 Position;

        public Missile(int XInitialPos, int YInitialPos)
        {
            Position = new Vector2(XInitialPos, YInitialPos);
        }

        public void Move()
        {
            Position.Y = Position.Y - 8;
        }
        public void MoveMissile()
        {
            Position.Y = Position.Y + 8;
        }

        public Vector2 GetPosition()
        {
            return Position;
        }
```

}

i know how to invoke the move method to make the launcher shoot, however, i don't know how to invoke something randomly as to make the invaders shoot. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
code which invokes launcher to shoot in the update method:
 if (MissileFired != null && MissileFired.GetPosition().Y < 20) MissileFired = null;

            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Space) && MissileFired == null)
            {
                MissileFired = new Missile(LauncherXPos, 650);
             }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could add a method to your invader named something like `ShouldShootMissile`. It should probably take a representation of your game time as a parameter (maybe a `double` or an XNA `GameTime` object). This function would return a `bool`.

It could then use this information to decide if the invader is eligible to fire a missile based on various factors. These factors would probably be a constant factor indicating the maximum rate it can fire (once every 500ms) and then a variability (250ms). You could use the standard random number generator to computer the variability and return either true or false depending on these conditions.

Maybe something like this:

```
    Random rand = new Random();
    double lastMissileFired = 0d;

    private bool ShouldFireMissile(double time)
    {
        double fixedDelay = 500d;
        double firingProbability = 0.1d

        if (time - lastMissileFired < fixedDelay)
            return false;

        if (rand.NextDouble() > firingProbability)
            return false;

        lastMissileFired = time;
        return true;
    }
```

Warning, the above code probably has tons of problems in it and almost certainly won't fit your program cleanly, but hopefully that gives you a clearer picture of what I meant. I decided to change the 250ms variable delay to just a probability chance that it will fire.

You would run the code above on every update of the invader

```
if (invader.ShouldFireMissile())
    invader.FireMissile();
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. Would it be asking too much if i got you to provide a sample code?. Thanks.

Comment: Well typically the `invader` object would be the one determining when to file the missile, not the projectile itself.